# Javascript sliding Image Gallery - no jQuery

Tags: javascript

Does anyone have any tips on making a pure JS image slider? I am looking to have it pause after each image and restart after going through all the images. All that I can find are jQuery plugins and I am look to do this with only JS.

Comment: The thing is, we're better at solving specific problems that you *are* having, not so good at anticipating problems you *might* have when you start implementing a solution. I'm sorry, but I think you'd do better to start building something, and then come back if, or when, you run into a problem we can help with. Oh, and here's the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions), for guidance on the sorts of question we tend to accept, and [those we don't](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: You could probably see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AZJzz/4/) and figure it out. Emphasis on the latter part.

Comment: Thank you for your input on how to approach this. Sorry for the delay and being a noob lol, hit the books for awhile and came up with something similar to below but without the underscore variables; haven't learned about those yet at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'd go for something like this:

```
var sliderTool = {
    _totalItems : 0,
    _visibleItems : 6,
    _currentOffset : 0,
    _timeout : null,
    next : function(){
        ...
    },
    prev : function(){
        ...
    },
    play : function(){
        ...
    },
    pause : function(){
        ...
    }
};
```

as a base.

every time you set timeout, save it into the _timeout field so you can clearTimeout(sliderTool._timeout) whenever you want.
next and prev can contain animations or just a simple image replacement. you can add a separate timeout for animation and for intervals between slides.

you can add an "add()" method to the sliderTool and on window.load or "body onload" add all the images and then run the start() method. you can also dynamically add images after page is loaded

maybe also add init() for autoloading and basic setup.

again, this is a basic draft of a possible solution. once you get running you'll probably run into more specific questions. Overall, as an approach, i recommend trying to come up with some solution first before asking for a general advice ;)

Comment: Galchen,
Thank you for responding to my question. Sorry I didn't respond earlier, I have been spending a lot of time in JS books and actually came up with a slide script in a similiar form like you demonstrated. I have not yet seen or read about using an underscore with a variable. I'll have to look into it.